# Login to ssh server without password

Tags: windows-7, ssh

I have a user with no password set on my Win7. Now i'd like to log in that user to a openSSHd server running on the system. How can i configure the ssh server to login that user without using ssh key-based authentication and without setting a password in the system itself?

Answer (score 1):

In your sshd_config set PermitEmptyPasswords to yes and PasswordAuthentication to yes